# При попытке сдеалать push из консольной версии git выдаёт ошибку 403

Tags: git

Создал новую учётку на GitHub. Создал в ней новый репозиторий. В консольной версии гит-клиента выполнил команду `clone` - получил предупреждение:
`warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository`. Разумеется он пустой -  подумал я - ведь я его только создал. После чего создал в папке файл. Сделал комит. Затем попытался сделать `push` и получил следующую ошибку:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Воспользовавшись переводчиком узнал, что меня просят убедиться в правильности и в, том что хранилище существует. Хоть я итак был в этом убежден, но, всё же, проверил ещё раз. На сайте стоит галочка, что репозиторий доступен всем, а то что есть нужная папка это само-собой разумеющееся - я как раз из этой папки и делал все команды.

Даже когда делал команду `clone`, git создал ещё одну вложенную папку с таким же названием. Так что же мне делать? Вроде бы все условия выполнены, а файл как был только в локальном репозитории, так там и лежит и в удалённый не улетает. Может у кого-нибудь была аналогичная проблема, как решили? А то вся работа из-за этого встала.

Comment: Покажите `git remote -v`

Comment: https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

Comment: Первая строка сообщения показывает, что нет ключей доступа от репозитория. Нет ключей от SSH. Если вы не знаете что это такое, то рекомендую попробовать начать с HTTPS протокола, закачивать по нему. Он не будет просить SSH ключ, а будет просить пароль от удалённого репозитория. Позже, когда будете готовы или надоест вводить пароль - вы сможете установить ключ и сменить путь к репозиторию (remote). Для каждой ОС свои инструкции по устновки ключей.

Comment: @AlexeyTen выполнил команду git remote -v и вот что получил: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Excel\VBA.git\VBA>git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:newGithubAccount/newGithubAccountProject.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:newGithubAccount/newGithubAccountProject.git (push) не знаю правда чем это мне может помочь

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду что нужно сделать клон про протоколу HTTPS? Для этого зашёл на сайт где была соответствующая ссылка, но той страницы с ссылками больше нет. Где можно посмотреть эту ссылку? И где можно взять этот SSH ключ и как его применить?                 
PS. У меня Windows 10